# Eclipse's equivalent to Visual Studio's .config files?

Tags: .net, eclipse, visual-studio, web-config, app-config

In Visual Studio there is this feature where you create two versions of a .config file. One version that contains parameters for a production environment, and another that contains parameters for a development environment. While I develop and debug an app, the development version of the file is used. When I deploy the app (for example, publish to a web server), the production version of the file is used.

Is there a similar functionality for .properties files (or any other file) in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is done by setting up multiple launch configurations. These aren't managed as files, but from the run button on the Eclipse toolbar. What you configure in the launch configuration will differ depending on the technologies that you are using. For Java, you would typically set system properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this answer.
**Debugging:**
You can simulate VS in different Debug launch configurations. 
**Deploying:**
   You can use custom ANT script with targets for building for various environments. Basically, you have to throw in the environment configuration files in a resource folder somewhere and each ant target would pick up the appropriate configuration file.